# Argparse with default file paths running from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, argparse

I'm a beginner to python.

I have the following code in my python script, I run the script from the command line but I'd like to run from jupyter notebook instead by passing it paths to the document

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('--names-file', required=True, type=str, help="names file")
   parser.add_argument('--class-file', required=True, type=str, help="class file")
   parser.add_argument('--registration-file', required=True, type=str, help="registration file")

   args=parser.parse_args()
   for f in [args.names_file, args.class_file, args.registration_file]:
   if not Path(f).exists():
   print("File doesn't exist")
   sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `%run` jupyter magic line function, or `!command line`:

command line / jupyter magic line:

```
%run full_filename_including_path arguments
```

or, a command line using `!` as a prefix:

```
!ipython full_filename_including_path arguments
```

Comment: thank you, where exactly do I add that within my code?

Comment: You need to run this as a single line inside a jupyter notebook cell